# STM32F1 (Standard Peripheral Library ) Why stm32 work failed if not define USE_FULL_ASSERT

Tags: assert, stm32

Im not good in english, so I'm sorry for my english fisrt, please be patient !

I'm working with stm32f103 and USART2 with RX interrupt. 36 bytes of data are sent continuously every 20ms, If there is no data received via USART then the chip works fine, and if the data is received, the chip is suspended somewhere.
But if I add #define USE_FULL_ASSERT then the chip works fine.

Can someone explain to me?

Comment: can you provide the code?

Comment: ofcourse erenbasturk! I'll up code to github and give link to you.

Comment: This is my code, erenbasturk

Comment: https://github.com/loiefy/USART2_USE_FULL_ASSERT